# Disable Visual Studio warning CS2008

Tags: visual-studio

I have a visual studio project (VS2012) that just contains some configuration files.  When I build I get the following warning:

CSC : warning CS2008: No source files specified [C:\Project\Config\Config.csproj]

Is there any way to disable this warning?

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem with VS2017 (`<nowarn>` attribute didn't work).  Adding an empty `VersionInfo.cs` prevented the build warning.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the project's property page in your Solution Explorer. On the build tab, you can disable the warning using its warning number.

This describes the options available there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kb4wyys2(v=vs.100).aspx

If you ever have actual code that triggers warnings, it can be disabled like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/441722ys(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: That isn't working.  I put in both CS2008 and 2008.  I also tried to set the warning level to 0.

Comment: Try as I might, I can't even get the warning to show up, at least not in VS2013. :(

Comment: It only shows up if I run msbuild from the command line with the  /p:Configuration=Release flag.

Comment: And you are using `/nowarn:CS2008` ?